# How do i use a field of a json ojected to find another field of a different json object? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, json

Basically i have a Get request that returns me a response with multiple json objects. I need to get a specific json object based on his name, manipulate that name and find the id of another object based on that modified name (in javascript). 
Example:

- I have a json with name: " XXXX Published", id: "1".
- I need to get the name, change it to "XXXX Restricted" and find what is the id of the object with that name.

Can anyone give me a code snippet from which to work my way up?

Comment: Do you get the objects in an array? Can you show an example reponse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've assumed the response format in this response, let me know if it's not correct.

```js
    const response = [
        {id: 1, name: "XXXX Published"}, 
        {id: 2, name: "XXXX Restricted"}, 
        {id: 3, name: "h3"}
    ]

    function replaceName(findName, name) {
        const index = response.findIndex(i => i.name === findName)
        if(index !== -1) {
            response[index].name = name;
        }
    }

    const oldName = "XXXX Published";
    const newName = 'XXXX Restricted'

    // This is the id that already has the new name
    const originalId = response.find(i => i.name === newName)?.id;

    // This mutates the response and changes the name
    replaceName(oldName, newName)
```

Comment: Thank you very much :)